# How to shorten a repetitive part of basic python code?

Tags: python, random

I am new to coding, and just started learning Python last week. I made this Powerball number generator to practice:

```
import random

print(random.randrange(1, 70))

import random

print(random.randrange(1,70))

import random

print(random.randrange(1, 70))

import random

print(random.randrange(1,70))

import random

print(random.randrange(1, 70))

import random

print(random.randrange(1,27))
```

**I am wondering, how can I shorten this, since the first 5 "import random prints" are exactly identical?**

Thanks ahead for helping a noob!

Comment: Only import once, then use a for loop: `import random ; for _ in range(5): print(random.randrange(1, 70)) ; print(random.randrange(1,27))`

Comment: @mozway the last print had a different range though

Comment: @yem - They're importing 5x because they're a beginner: `just started learning Python last week` - passive aggressive questions don't help.

Comment: @mikeb Valid point. I deleted the comment

Answer (score 1):

To start, you only need to import random once before you use it for the first time. That should shorten it to this:

```py
import random

print(random.randrange(1, 70))

print(random.randrange(1,70))

print(random.randrange(1, 70))

print(random.randrange(1,70))

print(random.randrange(1, 70))

print(random.randrange(1,27))
```

then you can shorten it more by creating a loop as @mikeb said in his solution which would make it look like this:

```py
import random

for i in range(4):
   print(random.randrange(1,70))

print(random.randrange(1,27))
```

Also, while not so relevant for this specific code, a common way to shorten code that contains duplicate code is to place the code in a function like this:

```py
import random

def powerball(n):
    print(random.randrange(1, n))

for i in range(4):
    powerball(70)

powerball(27)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `import random` once, and you can use a loop:

```
import random

for _ in range(0, 5): # 0, 1, 2, 3
  print(random.randrange(1, 70))

print(random.randrange(1,27))
```

Note that `_` is a valid variable name and is typically what you use for the name of a variable that is not used. In this case, we don't care which iteration we are on (the value of the range generator) so we use `_` to show that we are not using it on purpose.

Comment: `range(0, 4)` -> `# 0, 1, 2, 3, 4` I don't think so ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
import random

for x in range(0, 5):
    print(random.randrange(1, 70))
```

Also imports you dont have to do multiple times. You just do it once in the file. here is some more information about python loops: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp